# Should my function be named getCountXxx() or countXxx()?

Tags: php, algorithm

Does count PHP (and others languages) functions in models (query a COUNT() in SQL) should be named getCount($params) or count($params) ? Which is better ?

Thanks :)

Comment: None is better. You pick one style and you stick to it. It's not about the style, it's about consistency.

Comment: It depends, is `count` a property that is being returned by the function, or is it a _procedure_ that counts something? Either way, what's important is to be consistent throughout your codebase.

Comment: Voted to close as opinion-based.

Comment: If you are counting records, then you can give the name as `getRecordsCount()`, so whenever you see this method after couple of years, instead of checking what is the logic written in the method, you can directly get the idea by looking at the method name

Comment: Yeah about that, [this question will be closed because it is too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The answer depends on opinion.

Comment: Why too broad ? It is a conception / naming question.

Comment: @BenR. It is not too broad, it is simply opinion based, and since there is no universal consensus on which one is good and which one is bad, nobody can give you any answer that would be universally valid.

Answer (score -2):

getCountXxx() will be a good practice,

Example :

```
function init_example(){
$user_count = getCountXxx('some data if required');
}

function getCountXxx('data'){
//perform count
return $count;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think if you want to access a data in an entity that contains a variable "countXXX", you should use getCountXXX(), without any parameter, unless, if you wan to count the number of element in something, you should use count, as you do the action of counting something.
We could also discuss about making countXXX() something like count(XXX)